# Is it possible to authenticate using JSF 2.0 and Glassfish without realm?

Tags: authentication, jsf-2, glassfish, servlet-3.0

I have a routine that checks if a couple user/password is correct (it simply ask another server and returns true or false). I would like to use it instead of implement a realm file or a jdbc realm. The reason behind this is because I don't want to manage passwords.
Is there any way to implement such an authorization?
I know that programmatic security in servlet 3.0 specifies methods like HttpServletRequest.login. Can I use my own login funcion instead? Can anyone suggest me how?

My application needs just a simple authorization model: if the user is not authenticated he will have access only to the login page; if the user is authenticated he will have access to all the pages.

I'm using JSF 2.0 and Glassfish 3.1.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to manage passwords could you use openid/openauth type libraries (a la StackOverflow)?

[Glassfish and OpenId](http://www.shareyourwork.org/roller/ralphsjavablog/entry/openid_serverauthmodule_jsr_196_with)

Comment: My users have a passord and they are compelled to use their password to obtain the grant for accessing the web pages. The only thing is that I don't have access to the password table (and I don't want to create another one for the glassfish realm). But I have the possibility to connect to the server holding the passord info and verify if the user can be authenticated checking if the connection goes fine. If that connection is down (for any reason) the user cannot be authenticated and no access to my web pages is allowed.